# How to traverse a Linked List in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I have a **Linked List** ( object with nested Objects ):

```js
let list = {
        val: 3,
        next: {
            val: 4,
            next: {
                val: 2,
                next: {
                    val: 7,
                    next: null,
                },
            },
        },
    };
```

I want to get only `val` in an array called `nums` :

`[3,4,2,7]`

Comment: Cool! What did you try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning a Tree Inorder Traversal Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544669/returning-a-tree-inorder-traversal-results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this generator function:

```js
function* iterList(list) {
    while (list) {
        yield list.val;
        list = list.next;
    }
}

let list = {val:3,next:{val:4,next:{val:2,next:{val:7,next: null}}}};

// 1. To traverse the list:
for (const val of iterList(list)) console.log(val);

// 2. Or to create an array from it:
let arr = [...iterList(list)];
console.log(arr);
```